# Android apk permission?

Tags: android, permissions

I try to update my apk to google develop console.
However , I get the weird error.

App use these permission in an APK are required to have a privacy policy set （android.permission.CAMERA, android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO）

My app has already had the code like these in manifest.

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>`

Comment: u need to set privacy policy url for your play account

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Warnings Your Apk Is Using Permissions That Require A Privacy Policy: (android.permission.READ\_PHONE\_STATE)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41234205/warnings-your-apk-is-using-permissions-that-require-a-privacy-policy-android-p)

Comment: Yes I have read these article . I still face the same error. I have <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>. apk still tell me I need to have privacy policy set on two permissions.

Answer (score 1):

basically, when you use those permissions your app has to have a custom privacy policy. Meaning you have to have a link to a website where you have a custom privacy policy covering what you do with those two permissions.

So in your app you have to add a link to the privacy policy you have created. You cannot not declare a privacy policy.

Comment: Thank for your response . I still have question how I can write these privacy policy in android studio and get the right apk ?

Comment: You don't write the privacy policy in the APK, you write it on a website and add a link to the site with the privacy policy.  [see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mr2id.png) <---- As you see there is an option inside every app to declare a privacy policy. You have to add a link there to your website and you will be able to upload the APK

Answer (score 0):

You can display the privacy policy on the first welcome page of your app
[image]

[image]