# How to get Device Id in flutter of both Android and IOS

Tags: android, ios, flutter

Is there a way to get the *device id* for android and ios, because when I do it for android using the device_info plugin, it says this:

> MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method
>   getAndroidDeviceInfo on channel plugins.flutter.io/device_info)

Comment: which device/simulator are you testing?

Comment: I am testing on the Nexus 5 and on the Iphone X

Comment: none of them works for you?

Comment: did you try this plugin ?  https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/device_id

Comment: the example at https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/device_info works fine, just make sure you're not calling `iosInfo` on Android

Comment: It wasn't working properly on the iPhone X

Comment: also not working for me on iphone X. Anyone has an idea why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get unique device id in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45031499/how-to-get-unique-device-id-in-flutter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[device_id](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/device_id)** plugin works fine now with iPhone also.

Bug fixed by them and also updated to swift 4.1.x

To retrieve the id just import (`import 'package:device_id/device_id.dart';`) and call

`String device_id = await DeviceId.getID;`

You can check change-log [here](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/device_id#-changelog-tab-)

Comment: This package is discontinued in flutter packages.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out you don't actually need a package all the functionality to get Device info is inside a flutter class called flutter.io.

You can simply tap into it with this line of code as an import :

```
import 'dart:io' show Platform;
```

then to execute platform specific code you can use :

```
     if (Platform.iOS)
 {//your code} 
else if (Platform.Android)
{//your other code}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me explain you this by device_info plugin.

Step 1 Add Dependency

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  device_info: ^0.4.0+1
```

Step 2 Import your file at beginning

```
  import 'package:device_info/device_info.dart';
```

Step 3 Create a async function to return device id.

```
deviceInfo() async{
  DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfo = DeviceInfoPlugin();
  AndroidDeviceInfo androidInfo = await deviceInfo.androidInfo;
  return androidInfo.id;
}
```

Step 4 Create a FutureBuilder() to display device id or perform any action.

```
FutureBuilder(
  future: deviceInfo(),
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snap){
    // do nothing...
    if (snap.hasData){
      //your logic goes here.
    }else {
      return new CircularProgressIndicator();
    }
  },
)
```

I hope that helps you.

Comment: It's known to be null sometimes, it's documented as "can change upon factory reset". Use at your own risk, and it can be easily changed on a rooted phone.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add version in pubspec.yaml like below and click get dependencies. 
   `device_id: ^0.2.0`
2. Add import Statement 
   `import 'package:device_id/device_id.dart';`
3. and call 
   `String device_id = await DeviceId.getID;`