# Flutter - Get Unique Device ID

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I am making an app with token based system. So users can buy tokens and using them they can make some actions.
Each user gets 10 tokens for free (as a trial version) after creating an account using email and password.

I want to prevent that user gets another 10 tokens by getting a new account each time and I was wondering if there is something like unique device ID for both Android and iOS devices?

Can I use this for that purpose? https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/device_id#-example-tab-

Comment: On iOS the the device check API exists for this purpose.

Comment: You can refer here: https://pub.dev/packages/device_info

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get unique device id in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45031499/how-to-get-unique-device-id-in-flutter)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use [device_info_plus](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/device_info_plus) plugin.

In your `pubspec.yaml` file add this

```
dependencies:
  device_info_plus: any
```

Create a method:

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:device_info_plus/device_info_plus.dart';
// ...

Future<String?> _getId() async {
  var deviceInfo = DeviceInfoPlugin();
  if (Platform.isIOS) { // import 'dart:io'
    var iosDeviceInfo = await deviceInfo.iosInfo;
    return iosDeviceInfo.identifierForVendor; // Unique ID on iOS
  } else {
    var androidDeviceInfo = await deviceInfo.androidInfo;
    return androidDeviceInfo.androidId; // Unique ID on Android
  }
}
```

---

Use it like:

```
String? deviceId = await _getId();
```

or

```
_getId().then((id) {
  String? deviceId = id;
});
```

Comment: It's known to be null sometimes, it's documented as "can change upon factory reset". Use at your own risk, and it can be easily changed on a rooted phone.

Comment: It's not worked. If i reinstalled the app the deviceId would change,

Comment: @NicholasJela The device ID can only change after the phone is reset.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad I have got 2 different deviceID on my same phone already. While my phone never reset.

Comment: @NicholasJela Maybe you should file (or search) for an issue on Github page.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad When I call it in the way instructed, I get an error `The await expression can only be used in an async function.`

Answer (score 0):

Yes thats the plugin you need. If you really want to

> I want to prevent that user gets another 10 tokens by getting a new account each time

You must as well check for rooted phone (it can change id)

You may want to consider using this [GET IMEI](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/imei_plugin)

Comment: I think Apple is not allowing to get IMEI anymore.

Comment: On Android it will return IMEI and on iOS it will return device id

Comment: if we use this plug-in then app asks to grant Phone access permission which is not granted by users generally. I have an experience of this plug-in.