# how to check whether app installed first time or installing second time

Tags: android, react-native, flutter, flutter-dependencies, development-environment

How can we recognize whether the app is already installed with the device or not. Like If user installed the application and when he uninstalled the app and installed it again. Can we recognize that Device is installed this application previously.

Comment: When the app installs try to store the device id on the server or firebase, and whenever the same user re-install the app again then check his/her device id is exist in your server or not. If not then consider the user install the app the first time. And also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7217578/5978440) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16869482/5978440)

Comment: Thank you @Sniffer Can You suggest me best package for get the device ID..I am using flutter environment...

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55570413/5978440)

Comment: @Sniffer I tried this yes it is perfect, But how can app understand that he is uninstalled it and installed it again.. How can I write condition, for it must only execute function when he installed app for second time..

Comment: @chetankoppal Hi, can you suggest to me how to detect the app in the reinstalled state?

Comment: When the user opens the app check the ID existence in DB, this is the way for finding reinstalled state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this pacakge

> https://github.com/react-native-device-info/react-native-device-info

you can identify device unique id by

> import { getUniqueId } from 'react-native-device-info';

and for flutter i found this lib

> https://pub.dev/packages/device_info

then you can save this id in your database, and you can query for same id to know if app was previously installed