# How to get device id in flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to use device ID and pass to a `FutureBuilder()` to perform some action.
Can anyone explain or provide some code to illustrate that?

I've tried using [device_id](https://pub.dev/packages/device_id) flutter plugin but no luck.

I've checked with [device_info](https://pub.dev/packages/device_info) but not sure how to use it properly with `FutureBuilder`.

Comment: No really, I read that earlier. but didn't solved my problem.
I wanted to handle return value with FutureBuilder.

Comment: Ohh ohk no problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get unique device id in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45031499/how-to-get-unique-device-id-in-flutter)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me explain to you this by [device_info](https://pub.dev/packages/device_info) plugin.

Step 1
Add Dependency

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  device_info: ^0.4.0+1
```

Step 2
Import your file at the beginning

```
  import 'package:device_info/device_info.dart';
```

Step 3
Create an async function to return device id.

```
deviceInfo() async{
  DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfo = DeviceInfoPlugin();
  AndroidDeviceInfo androidInfo = await deviceInfo.androidInfo;
  return androidInfo.id;
}
```

Step 4
Create a FutureBuilder() to display device id or perform any action.

```
FutureBuilder(
  future: deviceInfo(),
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snap){
    // do nothing...
    if (snap.hasData){
      //your logic goes here.
    }else {
      return new CircularProgressIndicator();
    }
  },
)
```

Comment: It's known to be null sometimes, it's documented as "can change upon factory reset". Use at your own risk, and it can be easily changed on a rooted phone.