# Flutter & Firebase- How to allow only 1 account per device

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am trying to only allow the user to make 1 account on the device so when he makes an account and signs out, and then trys to make a new account it will not make the account and say this device already has an account.I got the device id so far but I dont know what to do now.

Comment: The solution for this will be to get unique ID of device and patch that up with user details. So when anyone or that particular user tries to create account from that particular device you will check in backend if that unique ID exists or not by using `device_info_plus` package check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45031499/how-to-get-unique-device-id-in-flutter

Comment: how do i check if it exists

Answer (score 2):

create a table in your database where the combined columns: userid (from new account) and deviceid are unique.
use device_info package to get unique device id

method get device id

```
Future<String> getDeviceId() async {
  var deviceInfo = DeviceInfoPlugin();
  if (Platform.isIOS) {
    var iosInfo= await deviceInfo.iosInfo;
    return iosInfo.identifierForVendor; // on iOS
  } else {
    var androidInfo = await deviceInfo.androidInfo;
    return androidInfo.androidId; // on Android
  }
}
```

Comment: Where does `DeviceInfoPlugin` come from ?

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is use the unique device id and in firestore create a document in the user collection whose document id is the device id, then to verify that the id already exists it would be to use the following code

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('users')
    .doc(idDevice)
    .get()
    .then((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
      if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
        print('Document data: ${documentSnapshot.data()}');
      } else {
        print('Document does not exist on the database');
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Get device Id using [device_info_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/device_info_plus) plugin and store it firestore. check when user going to create new account, already that device id in firestore or not!.

```
                        DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfo = DeviceInfoPlugin();
                        AndroidDeviceInfo androidInfo =
                            await deviceInfo.androidInfo;
                        String androidId = androidInfo.id;

                        print('Android device ID: $androidId');
```