# How to get a unique identifier of a phone in flutter

Tags: flutter, imei, flutterwebviewplugin

Please I want to get a unique id of a particular phone using flutter since android 10 and ios don't support the collection of imei

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45031499/how-to-get-unique-device-id-in-flutter

Answer (score 3):

From Android 10 onwards it is restrict to collect unique identifiers.
This was achieved only in DeviceOwner previleged apps and systemapps.From android developer documentation  [Best practices for unique identifiers](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids) explained how to identify uniqueness based on different scenerios.