# Unique device id in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, deviceid

I want to get a device id or any unique number that can not be changed when someone uninstalls the app. This device is for both android and iOS and is in the flutter framework. I want this to manage my device management.

Thanks for the help.

I tried some of the most commonly used packages in flutter like device_info_plus and flutter_udid but IDs generated from these changes every day.

Comment: This should be handled by a server. You can't safely persist data on the device that will be available after uninstall.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get unique device id in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45031499/how-to-get-unique-device-id-in-flutter)

Comment: @Stanly no please read my question carefully I have mentioned my used packages and I didn't get an answer from that

Answer (score 2):

Use [flutter_udid](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_udid).

```
String deviceId = await FlutterUdid.udid;
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried [platform_device_id](https://pub.dev/packages/platform_device_id/example)

This package can help you to get deviceId in android, iOS, windows, macOS and even in web and linux.

After importing the package you need to use following code

```
 try {
      deviceId = await PlatformDeviceId.getDeviceId;
    } on PlatformException {
      deviceId = 'Failed to get deviceId.';
    }
```

Comment: I will try it but it was last updated 22 months ago. Will it support or work fine now?

Comment: give it a try and if you finds that it's working then use it.

Comment: kindly can you differentiate between this package and device_info_plus package?

Answer (score 0):

You can use @Rohan's answer also. `platform_device_id` package. [Read more](https://pub.dev/packages/platform_device_id)

---

There is guide for `device_info_plus` package [Read more](https://pub.dev/packages/device_info_plus)

- add package to your flutter project.
- Create a method like this:

  ```
  Future<String> getUniqueDeviceId() async {
  String uniqueDeviceId = '';

  var deviceInfo = DeviceInfoPlugin();

  if (Platform.isIOS) { 
   var iosDeviceInfo = await deviceInfo.iosInfo;
   uniqueDeviceId = 
   '${iosDeviceInfo.name}:${iosDeviceInfo.identifierForVendor}'; // 
  unique ID on iOS
  } else if(Platform.isAndroid) {
    var androidDeviceInfo = await deviceInfo.androidInfo;
    uniqueDeviceId = 
    '${androidDeviceInfo.name}:${androidDeviceInfo.id}' ; // unique ID 
    on Android
  }

  return uniqueDeviceId;

  }
  ```
- use it like this:

  ```
  String deviceId = await getUniqueDeviceId();
  ```

---

Note (updateded):

Don't use `androidDeviceInfo.androidId`. This would change when your mac address changes. Mobile devices above `Android OS 10/11` will generate a randomized MAC. This feature is enabled by default unless disabled manually. This would cause the `androidId` to change when switiching networks. You can confirm this by yourself by changing `androidDeviceInfo.id` to `androidDeviceInfo.androidId` above.

(Got details from @Ariel)

Comment: yes, I used it and the IDs are changings regularly.

Comment: check updated answer. I updated it

Answer (score -1):

To generate a unique ID for the device without collisions you can use this code

```dart
import 'package:id_gen/id_gen_helpers.dart';

final deviceId = genUuid;         // string
final deviceId = genUuid.hash();  // integer
```

from the lightweight and well-tested Dart package https://pub.dev/packages/id_gen