# How do I get a unique id for Android and IOS devices?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I need to get a unique id of both iOS and Android devices using Flutter. The reason is that I want to log in to an account in my application from only one device. When another device wants to log in, I will check whether it is the same device from my database and if it is not the same device, I will not log in. For this, I need a unique device id. How can I get it?

In my research, I found a feature called "identifierForVendor" on iOS devices, but I am not sure if this value is special for each device. I couldn't find anything for Android

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/a/58435979/21977414

Comment: IdentifierForVendor is unique and remains fixed as long as any apps you developed remain installed on the device. If all apps linked to your developer account are removed and then your app is reinstalled it may get a different identifierForVendor on the same device. You cannot really get a unique device identifier in iOS for privacy reasons. You can add your own unique he keychain. This will persist across app delete/reinstall but not across device erase

Comment: Even if you do limit the user to a single device you need to provide some way for them to clear this and select a new device when they replace their existing device for some reason.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe take a look to [FCM SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/manage-tokens?hl=en) who can generate an unique token per app install.