# Why I can't upload apk to Google Play? needs camera privacy policy

Tags: java, android, camera, apk, privacy

Every time I upload my apk to Google Play Console, it always says that it needs camera privacy policy, but I don't even have codes for accessing phone's camera. My manifest only asks permissions for :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I am using Android studio 3.4.1, compileSdkVersion 28 and buildToolsVersion 28.0.0, minSdkVersion 17, targetSdkVersion 28.
has anyone encountered this before? Thanks

Comment: May be some troubles with used libraries?

Comment: The culprit is probably one of your 3rd party libraries. Please see comments on this question, it may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41234205/warnings-your-apk-is-using-permissions-that-require-a-privacy-policy-android-p

Comment: I tried to remove some 3rd party libs and It now can be accepted by Google. Thanks