# Include Android Permission in Expo/React Native

Tags: android, react-native, expo, google-play-console

I built an Android app using `expo` and `React Native`.

When I try to release the app, I get the error:

```
Your app has an apk with version code 5 that requests the following permissions: android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE, android.permission.CAMERA, android.permission.READ_CONTACTS, android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO. Apps using these permissions in an APK are required to have a privacy policy set.
```

How can I add these permission in React Native or Expo? Or do I need to add something in the Google Play Console?

Thanks

Comment: Does [this](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/1272) answer your question?

Comment: @Rohit No, it does not. Thank you

Comment: In this question have good answer about warning [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41234205/warnings-your-apk-is-using-permissions-that-require-a-privacy-policy-android-p)

Answer (score 0):

Per the error message, you can add those permissions, but your app must have a privacy policy in order to use them.  You might want to take a look at the expo documentation on deploying to app stores:

https://docs.expo.io/distribution/app-stores/

> Additionally, a number of developers have reported warnings from
> Google if their app does not have a privacy policy, since by default
> all Expo apps contain code for requesting the Android Advertising ID.
> Though this code may not be executed depending on which Expo APIs you
> use, we still recommend that all apps on the Google Play Store include
> a privacy policy as well.

If you need help figuring out how to host a privacy policy, here is a good idea and guide:

https://www.jsparling.com/setting-up-privacy-policy-and-terms-and-conditions-for-react-native-apps/

If you need help generating a privacy policy, consider Firebase's generator:

https://app-privacy-policy-generator.firebaseapp.com/

You may want to include a link to the expo privacy policy, given you are using expo (https://expo.io/privacy)